# Parsing through a Sentinel-2 tile

Tags: python, sentinel-2, tensorflow

I downloaded a Sentinel-2 product and opened with rasterio.open() all the bands I want to use.
This returns matrixes with size 10980 X 10980

I need to parse through the image using blocks of 120 X 120 (I am trying to apply a TensorFlow model to the entire tile).

```
def read_bands(tile):
    imgpath=path+"\\"+tile+"\\"
    bands=rasterio.open(imgpath+"allbands.tiff")
    bands=bands.read().transpose((1,2,0))
    return bands # returns a matrix (10980, 10980, 10)

# parses trough bands with blocks of 120 X 120 predicts and forms the tile output
def predict_tile(bands):
    niterations=int(bands.shape[0]/120)
    tile=np.zeros(shape=(niterations*120,niterations*120))

    for i in range(niterations):
        for j in range(niterations):
            patch=bands[(i*120):((i*120)+120), (j*120):(j*120)+120, :]
            y=model.predict(tf.expand_dims(patch,axis=0))
            y=tf.squeeze(y)
            y=tf.argmax(y,axis=2)
            y=y.numpy()
            for x in range(120):
                for w in range(120):
                    tile[(i*120+x)][(j*120+w)]=y[x][w]
    return tile

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
for x in os.listdir(path):
    bandas=read_bandas(x)
    tile=predict_tile(bandas)
    im = Image.fromarray(tile)
    im.save(path+"/"+x+"/"+"clc.tif")
```

This code runs but when I analyse it within QGIS the results are weird. Which leaves me to suspect that variable bands isn't the real image. If I am correct how do I obtain the real image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading the entire dataset into memory at once, consider using [rasterio windowed reading and writing](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html).  Using rasterio windows allows you to read smaller chunks at a time, do whatever processing and then write the processed data, chunk by chunk, to a new raster that is the same dimensions as the new dataset.

Here's an example that might get you started:

```
import os
import glob
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows


def iter_windows(src_ds, width, height, boundless=False):
    offsets = product(range(0, src_ds.meta['width'], width), range(0, src_ds.meta['height'], height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=src_ds.meta['width'], height=src_ds.meta['height'])
    for col_off, row_off in offsets:

        window = windows.Window(col_off=col_off, row_off=row_off, width=width, height=height)

        if boundless:
            yield window
        else:
            yield window.intersection(big_window)


def predict_tile(patch):
    # do something with the (120, 120, 10) shaped numpy array of data
    # y=model.predict(tf.expand_dims(patch, axis=0))
    # etc...
    # assume we want a single band output,
    # so just drop the last 9 bands for the sake of the example
    return patch[:,:,0]  # shape is (120, 120)


path = '/tmp'
size = 120

for tif in glob.glob(path + '/*.tif'):
    with rio.open(tif) as ds:
        profile = ds.profile
        profile['count'] = 1  # assume output is a single band raster
        with rio.open(tif.replace(".tif", "_clc.tif"), "w", **profile) as out_ds:
            for window in iter_windows(ds, size, size):
                bands = ds.read(window=window).transpose((1, 2, 0))
                tile = predict_tile(bands)
                out_ds.write(tile, 1, window=window)  # write tile to band 1
```